# Как вставлять изображения в edittext, как в заметках?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-edittext, span

сейчас я использую `SpannableStringBuilder` для этого, но я не понимаю как с ним взаимодействовать, как удалить по нажатию на картинку, или как запретить ставить курсор внутрь куртинки.
вот мой код сейчас для этого:

```
                @Suppress("DEPRECATION") val d= BitmapDrawable(bitmap)
                d.setBounds(0, 0, edit.width, (edit.width.toDouble()*(bitmap.height.toDouble()/bitmap.width.toDouble())).toInt())
                var selectionCursor=edit.selectionStart
                edit.text.insert(selectionCursor, ".")
                selectionCursor=edit.selectionStart
                val builder= SpannableStringBuilder(edit.text)
                builder.setSpan(ImageSpan(d), selectionCursor - ".".length, selectionCursor, 1)
                edit.append("\n")
                edit.text = builder
                edit.setSelection(selectionCursor)
                edit.append("\n")
```

на первом скриншоте показано куда попадает курсор, если нажать на картинку, а на втором к чему это может привести.
[image]
[image]
Мой вопрос заключается в том, как правильно сделать прикрепление картинок в приложении заметок, или как обрабатывать нажатия и, что важно, находить ImageSpan, чтобы сохранить его, а потом вставить для просмотра?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вот есть способ например:

```
editText = (EditText)mRoot.findViewById(R.id.content);
ImageSpan imageSpan = new ImageSpan(preview);

SpannableStringBuilder builder = new SpannableStringBuilder();
builder.append(editText.getText());

// this is a string that will let you find a place, where the ImageSpan is.
String imgId = "[img=1]"; 

int selStart = editText.getSelectionStart();

// current selection is replaceв with imageId
builder.replace(editText.getSelectionStart(), editText.getSelectionEnd(), imgId);

// This adds a span to display image where the imageId is. If you do builder.toString() - the string will contain imageId where the imageSpan is.
// you can use it later - if you want to find location of imageSpan in text;
builder.setSpan(imageSpan, selStart, selStart + imgId.length(), Spannable.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
editText.setText(builder);
```

и вот есть подобное обсуждения [1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7818438/how-to-insert-image-to-a-edittext/14286662#14286662), [2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3341702/displaying-emoticons-in-android/4302199#4302199).